# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: keyDown argument must be an instanceof Keys: null error executing Actions Class commands in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, key, action

I have written Key Class code with Action Object but when I run it, it is throwing exception as pasted below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: keyDown argument must be an instanceof Keys: null
```

Comment: ok ... and what is your actual question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: keyDown argument must be an instanceof Keys: null
```

...implies that the [`keyDown`](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/#key-down) method is expected to be an instance of [**Keys**](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/#keys) but was ***null***

Possibly you have missed the import and you need to add the following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
```